# Functions that preserve equivalence relations

Tags: functions, equivalence-relations

Quick question: Let $X$ and $Y$ bet two sets and $\sim$ an equivalence relation on $X$.  I was wondering what it means to say that a function $f$: $X\to Y$ 'preserves' $\sim$ in this case.  Does it mean that given two equivalent elements of $X$, their images under $f$ are identical?  Thats what first comes to mind, but I just don't know.  Thanks.

Comment: It would be best if you could come up with an example and context, but that would be my guess, as well.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I was looking for fun at a friend's notes[1] (I can't link directly to the file, so if you're interested, click on Math55a and go to Proposition 2.1 on page 6) on a math course he took last semester, and this general notion appeared, as stated, in a proposition about quotients.  So there is not much else to 'contextualize' what I have more or less directly plagiarized.


  [1]: http://www.mit.edu/~evanchen/coursework.html

Comment: @user210544 I just updated your my answer, in the given context it is what you guessed.

Answer (score 1):

The preservation of equivalence relations under a function normally means

$$x \sim  y \iff f(x) \sim f(y) \quad \forall x,y$$ but here $\sim$ is not defined on $Y$, so as far as I know there is no general notion of this, as long as e.g. $X\neq Y$ or $f$ isn't a homomorphism of a certain structure.

**EDIT:** In the given context I can confirm what you said, the author means $$x \sim y \iff f(x) =f(y).$$

You are considering the functions  $f = \pi o \bar f: X \to Y$ where $\pi : X \to X/\sim$ and $\bar f : X/\sim \to Y$. This means that $\bar f$ (and therefore $f$ too) maps a whole equivalence class (the elements of $X/\sim$ are equivalence classes) to the same element in $Y$.

Comment: Try \sim instead of ~ to get $\sim$.

Comment: Well, you could think of sets equipped with equivalence relations, and the arrows between them are function preserving the relation (should be a category)